# app:bundleReleaseJsandAssets stuck at this and always gives an error for every build

Tags: node.js, react-native, apk, publish

I have tried many solutions but it always give the same problem on every project. 
I am stuck at this for more then 3 days. The possible solutions that i have tried are as follow

1. ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
2. { "presets": ["react-native"], "ignore": ["index.ios.js","index.android.js"] }
3. gradlew assembleRelease --console plain

Tried all these but no solution found for generating.[image]

Comment: I hope you are following instruction at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html. Also try it by running ./gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: I have tried that too. Actually this command is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in your root directory `./gradlew bundleRelease` this line bundle all the needed javascript to run your app

```
 $ cd android
 $ ./gradlew bundleRelease
 $ cd ../
 $ npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```